# jquery multiselect - remove "un-checkall" link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there anyway to remove the "uncheck- all" link from the heaer?

Im using ehynds version

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

```
$('#dropDown').multiselect({
     noneSelectedText: 'Filter',
     selectedText: 'Filter',
});
```

Example screenshot from their website
[image]

Comment: Well as a hacking workaround you could use `$(".ui-multiselect-none").closest('li').remove()`

Comment: remove `<span>' + o.uncheckAllText + '</span>` line 82 in the jquery.multiselect.js file or use use JQuery to hide the required span

Comment: Why all the downvotes when there are people who actually know what I'm talking about and helping me?..lol

Comment: Re why downvotes.. I'd assume they're because you haven't provided an easy reproduction, as per Amit's comment.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao...your solution was the quickest...:

Comment: GuruprasadRao's idea is a smart one, but this is usually refered to as a hack... Use built-in features whenever possible.

Comment: @Salketer..the problem is there does not seem to be a built in feature to remove parts of the header...just the entire header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the header option seems to be the work around that. The un/check all buttons are part of the default header.

```
$('#dropDown').multiselect({
     noneSelectedText: 'Filter',
     selectedText: 'Filter',
     header:false,//Or put your own HTML
});
```

The default header HTML is

```
'<a class="ui-multiselect-all" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span><span>' + o.checkAllText + '</span></a></li><li><a class="ui-multiselect-none" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span>' + o.uncheckAllText + '</span></a>';
```

Comment: That removes the entire header...I just wanted the "uncheck -all" link to go away :)

Comment: That's what I was expecting, that is why I commented to show that you could put your own HTML, so adding the default header part you want to keep should be easy...

Comment: Excellent....now how do I grab that span...there is no id on it? Or are you saying just put everything in the header but that last span?

Comment: Yes just play with it... I am not expert at jQuery UI and multiselect so I'll let you do the thinkering... But this is the safest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the HTML around the element you want removed, which is the middle `li`:

```
<li>
  <a class="ui-multiselect-all" href="#">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span>
    <span>Check all</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="ui-multiselect-none" href="#">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
    <span>Uncheck all</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="ui-multiselect-close">
  <a href="#" class="ui-multiselect-close">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Even without a specific class, id or name on the span you want to remove, you can find it by its content:

```
$('li:contains("Uncheck all")').remove();
```

While the span isn't uniquely identified, the elements containing it are. As  Guruprasad Rao commented, you can use the class on the anchor tag:

```
$('.ui-multiselect-none').closest('li').remove();
```

The following snippet demonstrates the text matching approach, by highlighting the element that would be removed. (Replace the `.css()` method with `.remove()`.)

```js
$(function(){
    prettyPrint();
    $("select").multiselect();
    $('li:contains("Uncheck all")').css( "background-color", "red" );//.remove();
    //$('.ui-multiselect-none').closest('li').css( "background-color", "red" );//.remove();
});
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/master/jquery.multiselect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/master/demos/assets/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/master/demos/assets/prettify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/master/demos/assets/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/master/src/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>


<form>
 <p>
  <select name="example-presets" multiple="multiple" size="5">
  <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4" selected="selected">Option 4</option>
  <option value="option5" disabled="disabled">Option 5</option>
  <option value="option6" disabled="disabled">Option 6</option>
  <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
  <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
  <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
  </select>
 </p>
</form>
```